# Regex Contains Multiple words

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to search in titles matching entire search terms.
My example is something like below

```
string exampleTitle = "apple orange banana";
string term1 = "app bana";
string term2 = "bana app";
string pattern1 = @term1.Replace(" ", "*.*") + "*"; //output:app*.*bana*
string pattern2 = @term2.Replace(" ", "*.*") + "*"; //output:bana*.*app*

//now test
bool isMatch1 = Regex.IsMatch(exampleTitle , pattern1) // true
//now test
bool isMatch2 = Regex.IsMatch(exampleTitle , pattern2) // false
```

Thus `pattern2` not match because banana comes after apple. However I need to true when matching all of words in search term without any order.

Comment: Why use a regex in this case? You may just split the terms and check if a string contains all of them.

Comment: because of performance concern. Also why not?

Comment: Just because of performance concern, do not use regex. If you are using `.*` in your pattern before some "fixed" pattern, think about using a non-regex approach. Backtracking is a regular performance killer in such arbitrary patterns.

Comment: In the term2 take the `bana` in the round braces: `(bana) app`. [Proof.](https://tio.run/##jZHBSsQwEIbvfYohp7auLfZoEQTxILgguuBBPGTjWANpUjKpVmSfvU5aV3ZR2CWXzMyf75@ZKDpVpMaxJ20bePikgG2d7EbFCodQ3GPTG@mvh84jkXaW6iRRRhLBnXeNly18JQAUZNAK3p1@gaXUNqXgGfX0DNI3lLGGRVEWs4CDbDuDKx0MwgUI2XEEzkvbIKyl5SPq3QcBfXv2o5wEf8tVLKexlgGr9gWdDKyxEXE5sXiuzkiFqQCxAJEXucjghC@ihrJ0fej6cM4YLkRk/g@s2sKqo2ATpsgjc95FWVr3wa1TmMK1cwY0LWVQb7FPXjwOxc2cSPc2tvidJ4sGEHyPE@OKv8cZLB69DnirLaZbYFYf8qyO9Kxmz1dp6IBpNZluks04fgM)

Comment: BTW, why are you using the `@`? It serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `(?=.*app)(?=.*bana)` instead:

```
string pattern1 = "(?=.*"+term1.Replace(" ", ")(?=.*") + ")"; //output:(?=.*app)(?=.*bana)
string pattern2 = "(?=.*" + term2.Replace(" ", ")(?=.*") + ")"; //output:(?=.*app)(?=.*bana)
```

You can limit backtracking and forward search with this:

```
string pattern1 = "(?=(?>.*?"+term1.Replace(" ", "))(?=(?>.*?") + "))"; //output:(?=(?>.*?app))(?=(?>.*?bana))
string pattern2 = "(?=(?>.*?" + term2.Replace(" ", "))(?=(?>.*?") + "))"; //output:(?=(?>.*?app))(?=(?>.*?bana))
```

Comment: Note that @TommasoBelluzzo's answer is a better idea, and almost 5 times faster.

Comment: Yes! I tested. it is 40 times faster in my real app.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions can be tricky here. Use this approach instead:

```
String exampleTitle = "apple orange banana";
String terms = "app bana";
Boolean found = true;

// let's clean things up for malformed input with RemoveEmptyEntries
foreach (String term in terms.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    found &= exampleTitle.Contains(term);
```

Using `LINQ` instead:

```
// let's clean things up for malformed input with RemoveEmptyEntries
String[] terms = terms_list.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Boolean found = terms.All(term => exampleTitle.Contains(term));
```

Comment: I would suggest using LINQ to handle any number of terms.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your first answer only works for two terms.

Comment: Don't you wonder why `Split` doesn't use `params` and put other arguments first?

Comment: What do you think LINQ does internally? It's something like 10 times slower: http://rextester.com/ZWV74414

Comment: What do you think LINQ does internally? Running tests on LINQ versus `foreach` in LINQPad with optimization shows LINQ is about 13% slower. I am running the tests a million times against both original searches. Putting your rextester in a loop shows between 3% and 25% slower. See http://aakinshin.net/blog/post/stopwatch/

Comment: Tahnk you @TommasoBelluzzo I am looking for Regex solution. I have already know Linq solution.

Answer (score -1):

> I need to true when matching all of words in search term without any order

This could be more clearly expressed as:

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(exampleTitle, ".*app.*") && Regex.IsMatch(exampleTitle, ".*bana.*);
```

As noted in the other answer, there are non-regex ways to do substring matching that may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But that is not the solution I need. I am looking for a dynamic solution. Because search term can include multiple words.

Comment: @MehmetOtkun `^<label(?=.*\b(for=))`